# How to install Mahout on Windows 8.1?

Tags: apache, hadoop, cygwin, mahout

My goal is to build up a recommendation system and after going through many articles, I came across **Mahout** as a simple, yet effective way to go on. I already have **XAMPP** installed on my system.

How can I install Mahout? I need the complete instructions since I have neither worked with cygwin before, nor have I worked with Hadoop, and everywhere I see, I see these two mentioned very frequently. I first need to install it on my localhost before going on installing it on the server.

Comment: wouldn't be easier to put all your stuff on a linux machine? (then, you can just follow standard procedures and docs...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a detailed instructions page to install Apache Mahout with Hadoop in windows. Its bit tedious, but can be done anyway.

http://alans.se/blog/2010/mahout-on-hadoop-in-cygwin/